# Show that $\{ v : \langle v, v\rangle > 0$ is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

> Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space equipped with a symmetric bilinear form $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$. Then prove the subset $V^+$ is a subset, where $V^+$ is the set of all $v$ such that if $v$ is nonzero, then $\langle v,v\rangle > 0$.

I showed that $0$ is vacuously in the set, and that $$v\in V^+ \implies cv\in V^+, \quad c\in K.$$ I don’t know where to start to show that $$v,w\in V^+ \implies v+w\in V^+.$$

Comment: what is your definition of "scalar product"?  There are a few different definitions, so it would be good to know which one you are using.

Comment: I meant just any symmetric bilinear form. Sorry about that, I changed it.

Comment: The way that your question is phrased, it is not clear that $0 \in V^+$.  It certainly doesn't satisfy $\langle 0,0\rangle > 0$, hence I suspect hat you meant to explicitly include zero.  You also ask whether $V^+$ is a subspace in the title, but ask if it is a subset in the body of the question.  I assume that you meant to write "subspace" in the question, but it is not clear, and I did not want to accidentally change the meaning of your question while making some other quality-of-life edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner product (scalar product) is always [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition), so we have $\langle v,v\rangle > 0$ for any $v\neq 0$ and $\langle 0,0\rangle = 0$. Hence what you describe as $V^+$ is in fact all of $V$ and of course $V^+=V$ is a subspace of itself.

Please comment if I misunderstood your question, it seems a bit trivial.

---

For an arbitrary symmetric bilinear form, the statement is false: Consider the symmetric bilinear form $b(v,w)=v_1w_1-v_2w_2$ on $\mathbb R^2$. This yields
$$
V^+ = \{(0,0)\}\cup\{\, (v_1,v_2) \in\mathbb R^2 \,:\, |v_1|>|v_2|\,\},
$$
which is not a subspace. For example, $(2,1)$ and $(-2,1)$ are in $V^+$ but their sum $(0,2)$ isn't.

Comment: I will edit my definition of scalar product, apologies. That wasn’t quite the definition I was getting at.

Comment: I meant any symmetric bilinear form. Just edited that in now.

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath In that case the statement is false. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. That helped.